# Is it possible to keep the properties of the keyframe once it has finished?

Tags: css, animation

I have created a bit of code and I want to make it so I can click the red box and that it will move and stay in that position. Is there a way of doing this? do I need to us JS? I want it to stay at the top and also is there a way to make it so when I just hover over it once then it will move because at the moment when I make it hover, when the mouse is no longer over the div it will just stop the animation. Any input is appreciated :).

This is the code that I currently have (HTML then CSS). please let me know if you have any input or feedback. I am still new to HTML and CSS so some things might be a little sloppy.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />

  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="textbox"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body{
  background-color: rgb(21,21,21);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container{
  height: 425px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: rgb(43, 238, 252);
  border-radius: 25px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: end;
}

.textbox{
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: rgb(43, 238, 252);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 22px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 22px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  background-color: red;
}


@keyframes texboxMove{
  from {border-bottom-left-radius: 22px;}
  to {border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;}
  from {border-bottom-right-radius: 22px;}
  to {border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;}
  from {margin-bottom: 0%;}
  to {margin-bottom: 90%;}
  from {border-top-left-radius: 0px;}
  to {border-top-left-radius: 22px;}
  from {border-top-right-radius: 0px;}
  to {border-top-right-radius: 22px;}
}

.textbox:active{
  animation-name: texboxMove;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

Comment: [`animation-fill-mode: forwards;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)